# How do I add graphicname like figurename?

Tags: environments, counters, nameref

MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\newfloat{Grafik}{htbp}{loa}

\begin{document}

\chapter{A}

\section{B}

\begin{figure}[h!]\centering
\includegraphics[scale=.4]{example-image-a}
\captionof{figure}{Image}
\end{figure}

\begin{center}
\def\width{3}
\def\hauteur{3}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm, y=1cm, semitransparent]
\draw[step=1mm, line width=0.1mm, black!30!white] (0,0) grid (\width,\hauteur);
\draw[step=5mm, line width=0.2mm, black!40!white] (0,0) grid (\width,\hauteur);
\draw[step=5cm, line width=0.5mm, black!50!white] (0,0) grid (\width,\hauteur);
\draw[step=1cm, line width=0.3mm, black!90!white] (0,0) grid (\width,\hauteur);
\end{tikzpicture}
\captionof{Grafik}{Bla Bla}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

And output

[image]

How do I print `Grafik 1.1`, `Grafik 1.2` ...?

And `\newfloat{Graf\/ik}{htbp}{loa}` doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- The `\newfloat` has an optional argument to specify if the counter should be used within a sectioning level:
- to change the floatname you can use `\floatname{Grafik}{Graf\/ik}`

---

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\newfloat{grafik}{htbp}{loa}[chapter]
\floatname{grafik}{Graf\/ik}

\begin{document}

\chapter{A}

\section{B}

\begin{figure}[h!]\centering
\includegraphics[scale=.4]{example-image-a}
\caption{Image}
\end{figure}

\begin{grafik}
\centering
\def\width{3}
\def\hauteur{3}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm, y=1cm, semitransparent]
\draw[step=1mm, line width=0.1mm, black!30!white] (0,0) grid (\width,\hauteur);
\draw[step=5mm, line width=0.2mm, black!40!white] (0,0) grid (\width,\hauteur);
\draw[step=5cm, line width=0.5mm, black!50!white] (0,0) grid (\width,\hauteur);
\draw[step=1cm, line width=0.3mm, black!90!white] (0,0) grid (\width,\hauteur);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Bla Bla}
\end{grafik}

\end{document}
```

[image]